# MEAN stack project not support success keyword

Tags: mean-stack

**success** keyword not support my MEANstack project. how I fix this. please help me..
[my MEANstack project controller.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PE4p.png)

Comment: Can you please be a little bit more specific? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

**Use then() instead of success()**

For versions up to Angular v.1.6, you have to use then method. The then() method takes two arguments: a success and an error callback which will be called with a response object.

Example:

$`http.get('api/url-api').then(successCallback, errorCallback);`